# Why are my operators in Timber/Twig not working for my conditional statements?

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I am running a number of `if`, `elseif` and `and` statements in Timber/Twig in my custom WordPress theme that I am developing. But I seem to be having issues properly evaluating these statements especially with dates involved and the multiple `and`'s - I am just wondering if I am maybe not doing it correctly or maybe I can't use more than one `and` in a statement ?? Here is a my sample data:

```
{% if datenow < launchdate %}
  {# Do not show Products #}
{% elseif datenow > launchdate and post.product_widget.stock_qty > '0' %}
  {# Display the Products #}
{% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < '500' %}
  {% if post.product_widget.stock_qty < '400' and datenow < seasonend %}
    {# Run a 10% discount until stock drop below 200 items #}
  {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < '200' and datenow < seasonend %}
    {# Price products back at regular price #}
  {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < '100' and datenow < seasonend and post.sale_status %}
    {# Display products banner and bump to top of site #}
  {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < '50' and datenow < thanksgvng and datenow < seasonend %}
    {# Get another 100 items to last until season ends #}
  {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty > '10' and datenow < thanksgvng and datenow < seasonend %}
    {# Display shortage on hand and urge to buy now #}
  {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty > '40' and datenow > thanksgvng and datenow < seasonend %}
    {# Run Sale of the season on remaining stock #}
  {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < '10' and datenow > thanksgvng and datenow < seasonend %}
    {# Double the discount on remaining stock #}
  {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < '0' and datenow > thanksgvng and datenow < seasonend %}
    {# Thank-you but we are now out of stock on this item, please check back next year! #}
  {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < '0' and datenow > thanksgvng and datenow > seasonend %}
    {# Hide product and remaining inventory #}
  {% else %}
    {# Display Error Code #}
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  {# Display Error Code #}
{% endif %}
```

It doesn't seem make a difference if I was using <= or >= or wrapping in parentheses `{% if (post.product_widget.stock_qty < '400') and (datenow < seasonend) %}` any help and enlightment will be a great relief as this issue has been a bit of discouragement.

~ Thank-you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is (probably) that your dates are strings. Convert them to a date first before comparing. Also it's not necessary to store the current date in a variable

```
{% if date("NOW") < date(launchdate) %}
   {# do stuff #}
{% endif %}
```

Second issue is that your second `elseif` will never be triggered if the `stock` is greater than 0

Third issue is kinda similar to the first one, if a stock is lesser than X the `if` will kick in and all the other `elseif` blocks won't be triggered. You have to reverse those around or add an extra constraint.

---

If tried to simplify your code to the following snippet and made some adjustments in the logic as well, especially for the shortage message. I imagine you want to show this message when the stock falls below a certain threshold no matter what.

```html
{% if date("NOW") > launchdate|date %}
    {% if post.product_widget.stock_qty > 0 %}
        {% if date("NOW") < date(seasonend) %}
            {% if date("NOW") > date(thanksgvng) %}
                {% if post.product_widget.stock_qty < 10 %}
                     Double the discount on remaining stock 
                {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < 40 %}
                     Run Sale of the season on remaining stock 
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {% if post.product_widget.stock_qty < 50 %}
                     Get another 100 items to last until season ends 
                {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < 100 %}
                     Display products banner and bump to top of site 
                {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < 200 %}
                     Price products back at regular price 
                {% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty < 400 %}
                     Run a 10% discount until stock drop below 200 items 
                {% else %}
                     Show normal situation 
                {% endif %}

                {% if post.product_widget.stock_qty < 10 %}
                     Display shortage on hand and urge to buy now 
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% elseif date("NOW") < date(seasonend) %}
         Thank-you but we are now out of stock on this item, please check back next year! 
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/iwfhrg)

*Replaced `date("NOW")` in demo so you can play around to test the snippet*

---

I also mentioned adding a constraint as a solution as well, this is what I mean with this,

```html
{% if post.product_widget.stock_qty <= 400 and post.product_widget.stock_qty > 200 %}
    Between 400 and 200
{% elseif post.product_widget.stock_qty <= 200 and post.product_widget.stock_qty > 100 %}
    Between 200 and 100
{% else %}
    Lesser than 100
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/kwahii)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to lay this out for me I am very grateful and will see if I can do some modifications! I just wanted to clarify that it is okay to do multiple `and' in a statement then if needed? (but I see nesting may work better) Also I was having a bit of an issue with the datenow variable to be on the EST time zone, how would I make sure it is?

Comment: See [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html#timezone) for more information about timezones in `twig`. Yes you can add multiple `and`'s in an if but for the sake of reducing (code) duplication (and more readability) I broke those up

Comment: Okay I appreciate the clarification! Also on your comment: "your dates are strings. Convert them to a date first before comparing" is this way you would recommend? Is this what you had in mind `{% set datenow = "now" | date("F j, Y g:i a") %}` or is there a better way I should know about?

Comment: No, so the *filter* `date` is used to output a string based on a `DateTime` object or a valid date string notation. But as shown in the answer above you can use the *function* `date`  to convert a (valid date) string to a `DateTime` object which you can use for comparisons.